# How to select and update from the same table in Msaccess 2007

Tags: sql, ms-access, select

I want to be able to select and update my current stock table

This is my query:

```
UPDATE current_stock 
SET current_stock.quantity =
    (SELECT quantity 
      FROM (SELECT * FROM current_stock) As current_stock1 
    WHERE current_stock1.stock_id=2) 
WHERE stock_id=1;
```

If i run the nested select without the update it works fine, but using it with the update statement always returns error: operation must use updatable query

Actual Problem:

I want to deduct current stock quantity by the required quantity field in the table Bom_dell according to the corresponding laptop id

Syntax error: (missing operator) in query express Dlookup ..

I'm guessing the nested Dlookup is not working

```
UPDATE current_stock 
SET current_stock.quantity =
    DLookup("quantity", "current_stock", "stock_id=1")-DLookup("req_quantity","Bom_dell","lap_id=DLookup("lap_id","laptop_info","model_name="Dell Inspiron"")")
WHERE stock_id=1;
```

According to you're suggestions I changed the code to contain SELECT statement and it works:

```
UPDATE current_stock 
SET current_stock.quantity =
    DLookup("quantity", "current_stock", "stock_id=1")-DLookup("req_quantity","Bom_dell","lap_id=(SELECT lap_id FROM laptop_info WHERE model_name='Dell Inspiron')")
WHERE stock_id=1;
```

All I need to do now, is add a for loop to deduct all the quantities in the current stock table

http://tinyurl.com/7eghddq << Here is the link to the image of my relationship table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Domain Aggregate Functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa212172%28office.11%29.aspx) can be used to avoid the "operation must use updateable query" error.

In your case, it seems you want to replace the quantity for stock_id=1 with the quantity from stock_id=2.  If I understood that correctly, try this UPDATE query.

```
UPDATE current_stock 
SET current_stock.quantity =
    DLookup("quantity", "current_stock", "stock_id=2")
WHERE stock_id=1;
```

Comment: I'm Sorry to edit the main answer to add another problem.. i'm confused about how to let you know :(

Comment: It seems your actual situation is much more complex than the example you gave us in your question.  My suggestion is to edit the question to include your updated information.

Comment: Thank you very much Hans :) Access Guru!

Comment: can you post the relevent bit of your datamodel, I am getting the feeling you are making this more complex than it needs to be

Comment: I'm not allowed to post pictures .. need a rep of 10 :(

Comment: http://tinyurl.com/7eghddq << Here is the link to the image of my relationship table

Comment: All I'm trying to do here is .. deduct the current stock based on the Bom (bill of materials) of the corresponding laptop model .. but i want to deduct multiple stock, so i would need to apply a for loop here .. but my first goal is to deduct one item sucessfully first

The BOM table only specifies which laptop required what stock by how much quantity .. so according to the form value .. a person says " I want this laptop" IT should reduce the raw material quantity from the stock table according to the BOM of that laptop id

Answer (score 0):

if you hold the stockId that a laptop relates to in the table as per this datamodel

[image: data model]

then you can update it using the following SQL

```
UPDATE (LaptopInfo INNER JOIN BomDell ON LaptopInfo.LaptopId = BomDell.LapTopId) INNER JOIN current_stock ON LaptopInfo.StockId = current_stock.StockId SET current_stock.Quantity = [Quantity]-[ReqQuantity] WHERE (((LaptopInfo.ModelName)="Dell Inspirion"));
```

Comment: How do i add a data model like this one to explain? Should i attach a picture? :-/